# Get current IP in JS (no third party services)

Tags: javascript, ip, webrtc

Is posible Get Client IP Using WebRTC JS API and the ICE protocol (STUN for public IP)?

Comment: You cannot get the IP of the machine in JS. Also note that it's not possible to get the IP of the machine on its local domain. It's only possible to use a server-side IP lookup and those will only go the the first external source of the client network, which is generally either the router or the ISP server.

Comment: you may, try just for instance, to load http://net.ipcalf.com/ and read: document.getElementById('list').textContent.substr(0,document.getElementById('list').textContent.indexOf(' ')), But no native js or jQuery function will solve your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, using WebRTC JS API and the ICE protocol (STUN for public IP).

More info [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips).

```
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    function handleCandidate(candidate){
        //match just the IP address
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

        //remove duplicates
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);

        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate)
            handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

    }, function(){});

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

        lines.forEach(function(line){
            if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                handleCandidate(line);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

Comment: This does not work in Safari browser gives error saying: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'win.RTCPeerConnection')`.

Comment: How is stun.services.mozilla.com not a 3rd party server?

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdp' of null`, not work as should in chrome unfortunately